# React custom hook does not give result of POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

The custome hook post method working fine at the same time the response adding state taking time.

```
console.log(jsonResult)
```

shows the response of POST method at the same time `responseData` shows null

**usePostQuery**

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

interface bodyData {
  message: string,
  author: string
}

const usePostQuery = (url: string, data?: bodyData )=> {
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const callPost = useCallback( async (data: bodyData) => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            title: data.message,
            userId: 15
          })
        });

        const jsonResult = await response.json();
        console.log('--------jsonResult---------');
        console.log(jsonResult)

        setResponseData(jsonResult);
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [url]
  );

  return { responseData, loading, error, callPost };
};

export default usePostQuery;
```

[image: Edit focused-forest-fcdofq]

```
const { responseData, loading, error, callPost } = usePostQuery('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

The `responseData` is not giving post call response

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (draftMessage && myMessage) {
      // submitNewMessage()
      console.log("post my message to server");
      callPost({
        message: myMessage,
        author: "Mo"
      });
      if (loading === false) {
        setMyMessage("");
        setdraftMessage(false);
        console.log("after ", responseData);
      }
      console.log("responseData ", responseData);
    }
  }, [draftMessage, myMessage]);
```

The fetch is successful because the console in side fetch response shows the API response.

Comment: Where are you logging `responseData`?

Comment: @Phil just added more details

Comment: You should pay attention to the warnings regarding your effect hook dependencies

Comment: @Phil What is the ideal solution to get `POST` method  response in custom hooks ?

Comment: Rather than writing all this yourself, consider [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your custom hook. The issue is in your effect hook.

It only triggers when its dependencies change, ie `draftMessage` and `myMessage`. It does not re-evaluate `loading` or `responseData` so will only ever see their states at the time it is triggered.

It's really unclear what you're using the `draftMessage` state for. Instead, I would simply trigger the `callPost` in your submit handler...

```jsx
export default function App() {
  const [myMessage, setMyMessage] = useState("");

  const { responseData, loading, callPost } = usePostQuery(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  );

  const handleMyMessage = (val) => {
    setMyMessage(val);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await callPost({ message: myMessage, author: "Mo" });
    setMyMessage("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <ChatForm
          onChange={handleMyMessage}
          myMessage={myMessage}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      )}
      <pre>responseData = {JSON.stringify(responseData, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit young-currying-ynr765]

Your hook controls the `loading` and `responseData` states so there's really very little for your components to do.